# Create 'tree' output from list of files

Tags: text-formatting, tree

I have a large list of directories and filenames in the format

```
drwxr-sr-x hamiltont/hamiltont 0 2015-03-11 23:54 Archive/Directory One/Subdir/
-rw-r--r-- hamiltont/hamiltont 21799 2014-01-10 12:52 Archive/Directory One/Subdir/file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- hamiltont/hamiltont 21799 2014-01-10 12:52 Archive/Directory One/Subdir/file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- hamiltont/hamiltont 21799 2014-01-10 12:52 Archive/Directory One/Subdir Two/somefile.txt
-rw-r--r-- hamiltont/hamiltont 21799 2014-01-10 12:52 Archive/Directory Two/Subdir Something/somefile.txt
-rw-r--r-- hamiltont/hamiltont 21799 2014-01-10 12:52 Archive/Directory Other/Subdir/somefile.txt
```

And would like to create the standard `tree` output. Specifically, only showing directories and only down to level 3 e.g. `tree -L 3 -d`:

```
├── Directory\ One
│   ├── Subdir
├── Directory\ Two
│   ├── Subdir
│   ├── Subdir\ Something
│   └── Subdir\ Two
├── Directory\ Other
│   └── Subdir
```

I can accomplish this with a decently-complex bash script, but I'm suspecting there is an easier way

Answer (score 4):

This wasn't available back then but as of `Version 1.8.0` (11/16/2018) `tree` has a `--fromfile` option: *"Reads a directory listing from a file rather than the file-system."*
So, if you properly format your sample `infile` like

```
Archive/Directory One/Subdir/
Archive/Directory One/Subdir/file2.txt
Archive/Directory One/Subdir/file3.txt
Archive/Directory One/Subdir Two/somefile.txt
Archive/Directory Two/Subdir Something/somefile.txt
Archive/Directory Other/Subdir/somefile.txt
```

then you can run

```
tree --fromfile infile
```

```
infile
└── Archive
    ├── Directory One
    │   ├── Subdir
    │   │   ├── file2.txt
    │   │   └── file3.txt
    │   └── Subdir Two
    │       └── somefile.txt
    ├── Directory Other
    │   └── Subdir
    │       └── somefile.txt
    └── Directory Two
        └── Subdir Something
            └── somefile.txt

8 directories, 5 files
```

To only show directories and only down to level 3:

```
tree -L 3 -d --fromfile infile
```

```
infile
└── Archive
    ├── Directory One
    │   ├── Subdir
    │   └── Subdir Two
    ├── Directory Other
    │   └── Subdir
    └── Directory Two
        └── Subdir Something

8 directories
```

Comment: Being able to only show a limited number of levels with `--fromfile` would be great, but my `tree` version 1.8.0 simply ignores the `-L` option when using the `--fromfile` option. So your last example is not valid, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own answer, but probably improvable:

```
# Find all lines with directories
# Remove all ls output before the path is listed
# Recreate the directory tree
grep '^d' archive_filelist.txt | sed 's|.*Archive\(.*\)|\"Archive\1\"|' | xargs mkdir -p
# Use tree as you would normally
tree -L 2 -d Archive
```

The directory list is a huge archive (200+ GB) so this approach takes a while